# Rails 3 delayed job - upgrading to Rails 3 breaks delayed_job tasks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, actionmailer, delayed-job

I'm in the middle of trying to upgrade pieces of our app to Rails 3, specifically our unit tests.  I'm consistently running into an issue with delayed job and mailers, in particular, namely that the mailers aren't getting "sent" when the test is run.

To test emails sent, we run them all through an "assert_email" method in our test helper, which looks more-or-less like this:

```
def process_delayed_jobs
  while Delayed::Worker.new(:quiet => true).send(:reserve_and_run_one_job) do
    # nothing
  end
end
alias_method :deliver_delayed_emails, :process_delayed_jobs

def assert_emails(number, skip_assertion = false)
  deliver_delayed_emails # start with a clean slate
  if block_given?
    original_count = ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.size
    yield
    deliver_delayed_emails
    new_count = ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.size
    assert_equal original_count + number, new_count, "#{number} emails expected, but #{new_count - original_count} were sent" unless skip_assertion
  else
    assert_equal number, ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.size unless skip_assertion
  end
end
```

We test on this like so:

```
assert_emails 2 do
  Model.action_that_sends_mailer
end
```

This code works flawlessly in Rails 2, running delayed_job 2.0.5.  On Rails 3 we are running 2.1.4.

Basically, this fails every time we test it, because "0" emails get sent.  The mailers themselves are upgraded properly, and I've removed the erroneous ".deliver" from the method calls to fire them off.  The delayed_jobs log is empty, so it doesn't look like anything is being processed.

I feel like I'm missing some kind of key (but easy) syntax problem here.  Any help is appreciated.

Edit: I should also note that I've started the delayed_job process on my local machine with both "rails delayed_job start" and "script/delayed_job start."  Neither fix the problem.

Comment: Show us what `method_call` is please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out to be something unrelated to delayed_job.